# NZEC error in python 2.7 MAXCOUNT codechef

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error

BELOW is the code for the problem MAXCOUNT from codechef.com. The code on submission shows NZEC error.
The code takes first input t as no. of test cases, then for each test case takes input n a integer and the next line consists of space separated n integers Basically I need to return the maximum occuring integer and its count as output.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
t = int(raw_input())
for i in xrange(t):
    n = raw_input()
    n = int(n)
    a = []
    a =  map(int, raw_input().split())
    print a
    count = np.bincount(a)
    print np.argmax(count),np.max(count)
sys.exit(0)
```

Someone please help me out with this error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is the use of the `numpy` module, which is not part of the standard library used on CodeChef. If you need to check `numpy` or another module in an online programming judge, a good way is to use a code sample that you know works and then add the import statement to the top before resubmitting.

For CodeChef in particular, try the basic [test](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TEST) with the following code, with and without the import statement:

```
#Test for modules
import numpy

number_in = int(raw_input())
while number_in != 42:
    print number_in
    number_in = int(raw_input())
```

As a suggestion, the `Counter()` function from the `collections` module will work on CodeChef, you may want to try that instead of `numpy`. I find however that for many of the problems on that site without `numpy` or using `PyPy` it can be quite difficult to meet the timing requirements for solutions.

Comment: Welcome. That is a good answer, well framed, grammatical and making good use of a code snippet.